# Select all Rows with "Now minus 30 minutes" in Oracle SQL (11g)

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, oracle11g

How do I express "now minus 30 minutes" in an Oracle SQL WHERE, so that I can compare it with a stored timestamp?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is either the `dateadd()` function or

```
systimestamp - INTERVAL '30' minute(1)
```

Comment: he says, dateadd is an invalid identifier. Also googled some tutorials for dateadd. all of them get the same error.

Comment: I put in the other solution that works for me, which does basically the same, just using INTERVAL

Answer (score 8):

```
where yourTimestamp >= sysdate - 1/48
```

Comment: why 1/48? how does that give 30min?